# minimize/remove white spaces with flexbox (CSS)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hey I created layout using flexbox and that how it looks like:
[image: how it looks like]

As you can see I got spaces from both sides of the picture which I want to minimize/remove. How can I do that? post my code below:

html:

```
 <div class="movie-container" *ngFor="let movie of moviesArray;let 
    i=index">
    <div class="upper-container">
      <div class="upper-left">
          <img src={{movie.poster}}>
      </div>
      <div class="upper-right">
         <div class="title-more">
            <div class="title-container">
              Title
            </div>
            <div class="more-button">
              More
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ranking">ranking</div>
         <div class="genre">genre</div>
         <div class="runtime">Runtime</div>
         <div class="director">Director</div>
         <div class="description">description</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

css:

```
.movie-container{
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    width:80%;

}

.upper-container{
    display: flex;
    height: 200px;
  }

  .upper-left{
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .upper-left img{
      width:40%;
  }

  .upper-right{
  flex: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  }

  .title-more, .runtime, .director, .genre, .ranking{

    border: 1px solid #222;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }


  .description{
      flex-grow: 1;
      border: 1px solid #222;
  }

  .lower-container{
    border: 1px solid #222;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .title-more{
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

I will appreciate if you can show me both options Minimize the spaces and also how to remove them completely.
Thanks by heart.

Update after @Temani Afif help- this is the result when I minimize the window{
[image: minimized window]

Comment: did you try `align-content:flex-start`?

Comment: yes it keep the space and just move the image to the left side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `flex:1` from `.upper-left` and adjust some CSS of the image. The `width:40%;` was the culprit, you limited the width of the image inside the container so the remaining will be the space you have.

```css
.movie-container {
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  width: 80%;
}

.upper-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 200px; /*use min-height to avoid issue with a lot of content*/
}

.upper-left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.upper-left img {
  max-width:100%; /*added*/
  max-height:100%; /*added*/
  height:200px; /*added */
}

.upper-right {
  flex: 1; /* 1 is enough*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.title-more,
.runtime,
.director,
.genre,
.ranking {
  border: 1px solid #222;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.description {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.lower-container {
  border: 1px solid #222;
  padding: 10px;
}

.title-more {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="movie-container" >
  <div class="upper-container">
    <div class="upper-left">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/300?image=0">
    </div>
    <div class="upper-right">
      <div class="title-more">
        <div class="title-container">
          Title
        </div>
        <div class="more-button">
          More
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ranking">ranking</div>
      <div class="genre">genre</div>
      <div class="runtime">Runtime</div>
      <div class="director">Director</div>
      <div class="description">description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thank you.please have a look at the post I updated with another picture. when minimize everything destroyed   @Temani Afif

Comment: @hindi1991 replace height with min-height

Comment: works great you are awsome. can you have a look at the post one more time please? @Temani Afif

Comment: @hindi1991 hmm, it would be a bit hard with the actual code... by the way you should probably make it another question, it's not good to keep editing to change the initial quesiton :) people will get lost ... keep the initial one then add another of for the last issue instead of editing. It will also avoid me to change the answer a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181446/discussion-between-hindi1991-and-temani-afif).